# Administer issues does not work as Anyone

Tags: sonarqube

I cannot get administration of issues to be active for Anyone.
I have added the group Anyone to both browse and administer issues for the project.
Anyone can browse, but not administer issues.

It works if i create a user and add it to administer issues (when logged in as that user), but i do not want to use users at all.
I want anyone to be able to administer issues.

I tried deleting the project and created a default template with Anyone for browse and administer thinking that perhaps the setting cannot be changed for existing projects for some reason, but that did not help.

Running sonarqube 4.4

Plugins:

- Checkstyle 2.1
- Findbugs 3.0
- Java 2.4
- PMD 2.2
- SCM Activity 1.8
- Scm Stats 0.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, to do actions on issues on SQ (SonarQube), you must be authenticated because SQ needs to keep track of who did what. By default, authenticated users in SQ are part of the "sonar-users" group. So you just have to add the "sonar-users" group to the "Administer Issues" permission.

Comment: Ok, but that is not what the documentation says? From what i understand it should be enough that the user (or anyone) is allowed to browse. So if browse is allowed for Anyone then one assumes that it would be enough to allow admin of issues for Anyone as well?

Comment: You're right, the documentation is not clear about that. I will update it, thanks.